# Загрузка Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Во время загрузки загрузочной флешки появляется чёрный экран с текстом: This is not a bootable disk. please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как её исправить

Answer (score 1):

Вроде понятно написано: флешка не загрузочная.

Я так понимаю, биос классический, а не uefi. Попробуй записать флешку прогой от Майкросовта или другой специализированной прогой создания загрузочных флешек.

Ещё есть вариант, что ты используешь файловую систему exfat, а твой комп её не умеет на этапе загрузки. Наступал на эти грабли, когда на одном компе система ставилась, а на другом с той же флешки - нет.